# How to bind the socket for the specific Ip address in the network?

Tags: c, sockets

When we are binding a socket, in the address field we can specify like this,

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Here it will accept the request from any machine, Here I want accept the request from the specific Ip address. 
For that I used like this

```
  inet_addr(ipaddress);
```

But it doesn't work, How to get the connection form the single Ip address?

Comment: what is `ipaddress`?

Comment: For your reading enjoyment: [see here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html).

Comment: @SouravGhosh - another system Ip address , where I want to request from

Comment: I think you are confusing INADINADDR_ANY for incoming requests. When you bind using this option, it allows server to take request on any n/w if. Consider multi-homed m/c. Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the networking stack to do that, you can do it at the application level.

After you've accepted an incoming connection, check the peer's address and if you don't like it just `close()` the connection.